# Is there a way to delay the execution of a function parameter in R

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

I have some data and I am trying to see if there is a relationship between the columns and the SalePrice column. In order to do this, I have created a function that that groups the values in the columns that are the same and averages the SalePrice.

```
 continuousVSalePrice <- function(contVar) {
  group <- train %>% group_by(contVar)
  group <- group %>% summarise(
    SalePrice = mean(SalePrice)
  )
  ggplot(data=group, aes(x=contVar, y=SalePrice, group=1)) +
    geom_line()+
    geom_point()
}

continuousVSalePrice(OverallQuality)
```

However when I run this code with R, `contVar` is getting executed when it reads the function, instead of `OverallQuality`. Therefore, the error I get when it is run is...

```
* Column contVar is not found.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Is there any way to make it so that the function is not executed when it is read, only when a parameter is passed? Kind of like lazy-loading.

Comment: https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quasiquotation.html

Comment: See also https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html